# NSFileManager doesn't read the kMDItemWhereFroms from NSFileExtendedAttributes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager

For my little program that I'm running called SourceControl I'm trying the following:
Read a file(that was downloaded from internet) at a certain (for now from a static) path on the computer.

The main idea is to get the source from where the file was downloaded.

like so:

[image: File source (image here)]

I've tried some code but what I get is a pointer to another object which isn't really what I'd like... I want to show the actual string like so:
"http://www.sunjets.be/_images/boekingsengine/grevas1_nl.jpg"

Get the `NSFileExtendedAttributes` to eventually get the the `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms`:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        //Static path to my file/image
        NSString* myPath = @"/Users/Verbe/Klassieke_Oudheid.JPG";

        //creating the filemanager
        NSFileManager *filemgr = [[NSFileManager alloc]init];

        //if the path exists, whiii it exists!
        if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:myPath])
        {
            NSLog(@"file exists!");

            //Set the fileattributes to the dictionary!
            NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [filemgr attributesOfItemAtPath:myPath error:
                                            nil];

            for (NSString* myKey in fileAttributes)
            {
                if ([myKey isEqualToString:@"NSFileExtendedAttributes"])
                {
                    NSLog(@"MyKey = %@ with attribute: %@",myKey, [fileAttributes objectForKey:myKey]);

                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"File does not exist!");
        }

}
    return 0;
```

The result is the following:

> 2013-10-11 04:23:32.167 CustomInit[1016:303] file exists! 2013-10-11
>   04:23:32.190 CustomInit[1016:303] MyKey = NSFileExtendedAttributes
>   with attribute: {
>       "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate" = <62706c69 73743030 a1013341 b8078c4f a88e8a08 0a000000 00000001 01000000 00000000
>   02000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 13>;
>       "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms" = <62706c69 73743030 a1015f10 3b687474 703a2f2f 7777772e 73756e6a 6574732e 62652f5f
>   696d6167 65732f62 6f656b69 6e677365 6e67696e 652f6772 65766173
>   315f6e6c 2e6a7067 080a0000 00000000 01010000 00000000 00020000
>   00000000 00000000 00000000 0048>;
>       "com.apple.quarantine" = <30303030 3b353235 37353463 663b5361 66617269 3b>; } Program ended with exit code: 0

Note that the `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate` and `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms` are actually there!

What's going on here and how do I fix it?

Comment: Those look like NSData blocks whose format is probably undocumented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are Metadata (Spotlight) attributes, so you're meant to use the Metadata framework. [Create an MDItem with the URL to the file](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/MDItemRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MDItemCreateWithURL) and [ask that item for its value for the attribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/MDItemRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MDItemCopyAttribute).

Like so:

```
MDItemRef item = MDItemCreateWithURL(kCFAllocatorDefault, myFileURL);
NSArray *whereFroms = CFBridgingRelease(MDItemCopyAttribute(item, kMDItemWhereFroms));
```

No plist-decoding necessary.

Comment: Could you give an example, @Peter?

Comment: @BenVertonghen: Behold.

Comment: +1 looks like a better way as it keeps the 'implementation details' out of your app

Answer (score 3):

Value return from `[[fileAttributes objectForKey:myKey] objectForKey:@"com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms"]` are apple binary plist (bplist00). Use `propertyListFromData:mutabilityOption:format:errorDescription:` function of `NSPropertyListSerialization` class for Conversion.

```
NSString* myPath = @"/Users/new/Downloads/TelephoneBill.pdf";

//creating the filemanager
NSFileManager *filemgr = [[NSFileManager alloc]init];

//if the path exists, whiii it exists!
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:myPath])
{
    NSLog(@"file exists!");

    //Set the fileattributes to the dictionary!
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [filemgr attributesOfItemAtPath:myPath error:
                                    nil];

    for (NSString* myKey in fileAttributes)
    {
        if ([myKey isEqualToString:@"NSFileExtendedAttributes"])
        {
            NSLog(@"MyKey = %@ with attribute: %@",myKey, [fileAttributes objectForKey:myKey]);

            NSData *whereFromData = [[fileAttributes objectForKey:myKey] objectForKey:@"com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms"];
            NSString *error;
            NSPropertyListFormat format;
            id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:whereFromData
                                                     mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                               format:&format
                                                     errorDescription:&error];
            NSLog(@"plist %@",plist);
        }
    }

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"File does not exist!");
}  



plist (
    "https://www.airtel.in/myaccount/BillGuide/RevamP/download?fileName=EA29BB",
    "https://www.airtel.in/myaccount/BillGuide/billSummary.action?param=myBillSummary&res=6DAED0342C197C"
)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I owe you one! 
So it eventually means the code that was spat out before, was a binary plist from Apple itself... Which we would catch up in our own Plist, (the same Plist as the preference list or is that something else?) Either way thanks a lot!

Comment: :) Yes, you can write that data to file. [whereFromData writeToFile:@"/p.plist" atomically:YES];